# SQL - Multiple Group By statements with counts

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, subquery

I'm writing a query for work in Microsoft Access.  The Raw table looks like this:

Columns

ColA  | ColB

aa | x

aa | y

bb | x

bb | x

The problem I am trying to solve is: For each distinct value in column A, what is the count of distinct values in column B?

Output would be something like:

aa | 2

bb | 1

I would like to take it a step further and only select those where the count = 1, so :

bb | 1

would be the only result.

I have found what I consider to be a overly complicated subquery to accomplish this, but I'm hoping someone has a more elegant solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select values of `A` that have only one value of `B`, you can use:

```
select t.A
from mytable as t
group by t.A
having min(t.B) = max(t.B);
```

This ignores `NULL` values when considering duplicates.  That can be factored in if necessary.  Also, the count seems redundant, because it will always be 1.

Comment: What if the number was something other than one, say 2.  Is there a similar query without a subquery?

Comment: @user1825257 . . . That gets harder because Access doesn't support `count(distinct)`.  I think a subquery would be necessary in that case.  It would be easy in just about any other relational database.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is:

```
SELECT X.A, COUNT(X.B)
FROM (
      SELECT D.A, D.B
      FROM MY_TABLE as D
      GROUP BY D.A, D.B
      )  AS X
GROUP BY X.A
HAVING COUNT(X.B) = 1
```